# django admin add extra content

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am not an expert in Django admin(
I have models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, max_length=128)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class DeviceHistory(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='device_history')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to add a table to the Django admin panel to the device's detailed page. There are two datetime inputs (start and end datetime). I need devide this time on hours, and check if exists one or more device history.
This is how I've got the array of data:

```
def get_device_history(device):
    date_first = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
    date_last = timezone.now()
    result = []

    while date_first < date_last:
        date_end = date_first + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        histories_exists = DeviceHistory.objects.filter(
            device=device,
            created_at__gte=date_first,
            created_at__lte=date_end
        ).exists()
        result.append([str(date_first), str(date_end), histories_exists])
        date_first = date_end
```

And I've got something like this

```
[['2023-11-08 10:03:00.577493+00:00', '2023-11-08 11:03:00.577493+00:00', False], ['2023-11-08 11:03:00.577493+00:00', '2023-11-08 12:03:00.577493+00:00', False], ['2023-11-08 12:03:00.577493+00:00', '2023-11-08 13:03:00.577493+00:00', False], ['2023-11-08 13:03:00.577493+00:00', '2023-11-08 14:03:00.577493+00:00', True], ['2023-11-08 14:03:00.577493+00:00', '2023-11-08 15:03:00.577493+00:00', True], ['2023-11-08 15:03:00.577493+00:00', '2023-11-08 16:03:00.577493+00:00', False], ['2023-11-08 16:03:00.577493+00:00', '2023-11-08 17:03:00.577493+00:00', True], ['2023-11-08 17:03:00.577493+00:00', '2023-11-08 18:03:00.577493+00:00', False]]
```

How can I add this data to admin page like TabularInline table? And how can I add two datetime input for search in different range?

Here is a picture of the functionality I need [image]